# Why are my speakers working but not my headphones?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my Asus G50VTX5. Sound works for the speakers but there's no sound from the headphones. Headphones are working fine in other devices.

Comment: Headphone: Make and model? USB or plugged into sound card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its an issue! I've opened a bug about this issue but canonical didnt give much attention. athough I've managed to put Headphones working

I've explained how to solve on page's bug report
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/660715

Answer (score 5):

This is a pulseaudio bug, still present on 11.10

As a workaround edit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf :

```
gksu gedit analog-output-headphones.conf
```

Than search for and comment this line like here:

```
[Jack_InputDevice]
#code = Headphone
```

Save the file and close gedit. Than restart pulseaudio with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Most people think this is an ALSA thing, but is not.

I reported this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/921397

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to edit the file and I struggled quite a bit trying to figure out why. I thought it was because of pixmap as I was getting an error message. I installed

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

error message was gone, but still not able to edit so I used the following command

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf
```

and there I was able to

I still get an error message everytime I save regarding a root file that does not exist, but it doesn't look like it's impeding the save process at all.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal end type:

```
alsamixer
```

Play around with the bars.
Use arrows to switch left-right or up/down to higher/lower the volume.

Answer (score -1):

Your headphone output is probably muted. Open the sound control panel and check that you don't have any outputs muted.

Comment: Downvoted because?? I've had this problem, and it was exactly the case that my headphone output was muted. Not saying it's the answer every time, but worth checking.