# Is there a way to disable auto-switch output channel when I connect headphones?  

Tags: sound, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my speakers working but not my headphones?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31317/why-are-my-speakers-working-but-not-my-headphones)

It kicked in after upgrade to ubuntu 11.10

when I connect headphones, output channel (observed through control panel sound section) switches to headphones and volume level in headphones is  extremely low

workarounds:

- set output channel back to speakers. Volume level in headphones pops in to normal
- switch profile in hardware section to some other and then back
- raise `Speaker` volume in `alsamixer`

Currently I am in a hurry and not looking for proper fix.

**Is there a way to disable auto-switch output channel when I connect headphones?**

PS. strange thing: when I run `alsamixer -c 0`,
there is no bar above `Headphones` section, just `|00|`, like they are not connected, therefore I cannot rise volume level manually

Comment: Check for files in `/var/log/....` that have a modification timestamp around the time you plugged the headphones in - maybe some task is bragging about turning headphones down. Try: `touch /tmp/now`, plug in headphones (cause the problem), then `find /var/log -type f -newer /tmp/now | xargs less`. Use `less`'s `G` command to get to the end of each file, and see what's up. You could also check for logs in your `$HOME` with `find $HOME -type f -newer /tmp/now | xargs less`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pulseaudio bug, still present on 11.10

As a workaround edit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf :

```
gksu gedit analog-output-headphones.conf
```

Than search for and comment this line like here:

```
[Jack_InputDevice]
#code = Headphone
```

Save the file and close gedit. Than restart pulseaudio with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Most people think this is an ALSA thing, but is not.

I reported this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/921397

Comment: Thanks! great answer. Also if you don't want the mic to switch do same modification to analog-input-dock-mic.conf

Comment: Or maybe analog-input-mic.conf...YMMV